# Python selenium wait for page to load without a condition

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want selenium to wait before taking a screenshot. When I use time.sleep(1) it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in 
    driver.save_screenshot('page.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/we
bdriver.py", line 1033, in save_screenshot
    return self.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/we
bdriver.py", line 1010, in get_screenshot_as_file
    png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/we
bdriver.py", line 1042, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/we
bdriver.py", line 1052, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/we
bdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/re
mote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/re
mote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path = 
'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', log_path=os.devnull)
driver.get('https://google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot('page.png')
driver.quit()
```

How do I wait for the page to load without getting this error?

I know you can wait for an element to load I just want to wait without any condition for it.

(of course, there is nothing more to load on google.com I just made this example to make the question easter.)

Comment: The error isn't due to the sleep, it's due to the `save_screenshot()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add a unconditional wait to `driver.get(URL)` in selenium, `driver.set_page_load_timeout(n)` with `n = time/seconds` and loop:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(n)        # Set timeout of n seconds for page load
loading_finished = 0                   # Set flag to 0
while loading_finished == 0:           # Repeat while flag = 0
    try:
       sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5)) # wait some time
       website = driver.get(URL)       # try to load for n seconds
       loading_finished = 1            # Set flag to 1 and exit while loop
    except:
       logger.warn("timeout - retry")  # Indicate load fail
else:
    driver.save_screenshot('page.png') # In case of flag = 1
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# this code will will keep looping until the element is find so whatever how 
# much time the page will take time to load .    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
itm = ""
while(True) : 
     try : 
         itm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath elem)
         break
     except : 
      pass
```

#### Furthermore:

```
# this function will find all the ements with xpath EXPR
def Finds(EXPR) :
    itms = ""
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            itms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(EXPR)
            break
        except : 
            pass
    return itms
#this function will find the elem had xpath EXPR
def Find(EXPR) :
    itm = ""
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            itm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(EXPR)
            break
        except : 
            pass
    return itm
#this function will find textbox or any thing you can insert into a text , this elem had xpath F , it insert text I
def Find_Insert(F,I) : 
    it = ""
    x1 = ""
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            print "find " , F
            x1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(F)
            print("1")
            break
        except : 
            pass
    it = x1 
    while(True) : 
        try :
            print "sending " , I
            it.send_keys(I)
            break
        except : 
            pass
#this function will find textbox or any thing you can insert into a text , this elem had xpath F , it insert text I and then press key C
def Find_Insert_Click(F,I,C) : 
    it = ""
    x1 = ""
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            print "find " , F
            x1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(F)
            print("1")
            break
        except : 
            pass
    it = x1 
    while(True) : 
        try :
            print "sending " , I
            it.send_keys(I)
            break
        except : 
            pass
    x1 = it  
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            print "Submit " , F
            it.send_keys(C)
            break
        except : 
            pass  
# this function will the elleent with xpath F and then clicke it 
def Find_Click(F) :
    it = ""
    x1 = ""
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            print "find " , F
            x1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(F)
            break
        except : 
            pass
    it = x1 
    while(True) : 
        try : 
            print "click" , F
            it.click()
            break
        except : 
            pass
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has an accepted answer, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.